# Access LinkedIn Profile's Job Title using API

Tags: linkedin-api

I try to access the profile's Job title, first name, last name, and company using LinkedIn API and PHP.

I have applied for LinkedIn Marketing Program on https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply then I found some posts on StackOverflow saying that it could take several months to get approved :(

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? (Can I get access to LinkedIn r_liteprofile? is it limited in the number of requests or paid? )

Do I need r_liteprofile to access LinkedIn Jobtitle or I need to request more permission access?

Thank you very much for you help.
Kind regards
Lamine

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is through google or bing, or any web search engines, which can kind of getting the "Headline", but not 100% accuracy.

`site:linkedin.com {query}`

By default, people put their Job Title as Headline.

Personally, I used Google Custom Search JSON API.

[image: LinkedIn Profile URL and Headline without Partner]

Good luck!